# Row echelon form of (augmented) matrix. Is there something wrong with Sage's implementation?

Tags: linear-algebra, sagemath

I am trying to solve the exercise *RREF.C10* from the [A first course in Linear Algebra](http://linear.ups.edu/html/section-RREF.html) free book.

The exercise aims at finding the [reduced row echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) of the following linear system:

$\begin{align*}
2x_1-3x_2+x_3+7x_4&=14\\
2x_1+8x_2-4x_3+5x_4&=-1\\
x_1+3x_2-3x_3&=4 \\
-5x_1+2x_2+3x_3+4x_4&=-19
\end{align*}$

After attempting a solution on paper, I looked for the solution with [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/):

```
C10A = matrix([[2,-3,1,7],[2,8,-4,5],[1,3,-3,0],[-5,2,3,4]])
C10b = vector([14,-1,4,-19])
C10M = C10A.augment(C10b, subdivide=True)
C10M
C10A.echelon_form()
C10M.echelon_form()
```

with the following outcome:

```
[  2  -3   1   7| 14]
[  2   8  -4   5| -1]
[  1   3  -3   0|  4]
[ -5   2   3   4|-19]

[  1   0   0 273]
[  0   1   0 315]
[  0   0   1 406]
[  0   0   0 479]

[  1   0   0 273 274]
[  0   1   0 315 312]
[  0   0   1 406 402]
[  0   0   0 479 479]
```

Unfortunately the reported solution from the book is very different:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  1\\
0 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  -3\\
0 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  -4\\
0 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

I wonder what causes this discrepancy. Is *Sage*'s implementation broken? Or is it just the solution from the book that is broken?

Moreover, why isn't *Sage* multiplying the last row for $\frac{1}{479}$ in order to have a leading $1$?

Comment: It's not "very different" in the sense that if you do divide by 479, then a round of operations involving the two last columns gives you what you wanted. I don't know why Sages doesn't do it. May be it is doing arithmetic over an unknown ring and is not certain whether $479=0$ or not? May be it is working over integers only?

Comment: The form shown "from the book" is called *reduced* row-echelon form, wherein leading ones have columns that are otherwise zeros.  The row-echelon form only requires entries *below* leading ones to be zeros.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: you were right on the integers. I changed the type to rationals (`QQ`) and now it computed the *reduced* row echelon form.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the problem!

Comment: @francescostablum: Now that you've done the research, this would be a good solution for you to write up as a self-Answer! (Your "update" would do fine IMHO.)

Answer (score 3):

Setting explicitly the type of the numbers to rationals (`QQ`), actually solved the problem, giving the unique *reduced row echelon form*, instead of just one row echelon form:

```
C10A = matrix(QQ,[[2,-3,1,7],[2,8,-4,5],[1,3,-3,0],[-5,2,3,4]])
C10b = vector(QQ,[14,-1,4,-19])
C10M = C10A.augment(C10b, subdivide=True)
C10M
C10A.echelon_form()
C10M.echelon_form()


[  2  -3   1   7| 14]
[  2   8  -4   5| -1]
[  1   3  -3   0|  4]
[ -5   2   3   4|-19]

[1 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 1]

[ 1  0  0  0| 1]
[ 0  1  0  0|-3]
[ 0  0  1  0|-4]
[ 0  0  0  1| 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Good sleuthing!  In order to relieve those who don't know about rings from needing to learn about them while preserving easy access to this functionality, Sage also has the `rref()` method for such matrices (reduced row echelon form):

```
sage: C10A.echelon_form()
[  1   0   0 273]
[  0   1   0 315]
[  0   0   1 406]
[  0   0   0 479]
sage: C10A.rref()
[1 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 1]
```

In fact, if you look at the section marked "Sage RREF Reduced Row-Echelon Form", you will see that Rob says the following:

> You may notice that Sage has some commands with the word “echelon” in
>   them. For now, these should be avoided like the plague, as there are
>   some subtleties in how they work.

Indeed, though you figured it out.   Good luck!